# Java - player collection - calculate win/loss

Tags: java

I have a collection of players that I can access using:

```
public Collection<Player> getAllPlayers() {
  return players.values();
}
```

I need to find the player with the highest result using player.getResult(). Then update all other players to a loss using player.setWon(). If players have the same result (a draw) I need to setWon(false) and not change their total points. Players who lose I need to minus their bet from their total and the player who won I need to add their bet to their total.

Struggling with the draw, how do I differentiate one player winning to multiple players with the same total winning? 
This is what I have so far:

```
//for every player in collection
  for (Player player : getAllPlayers())
  {
     //find the largest player result
     int resultToTest = player.getResult();
     if (resultToTest > bestResult) {
        bestResult = resultToTest;
     }
     else if (resultToTest == bestResult){
        player.setWon(false);           
     }
     else if(resultToTest < bestResult){
        player.setWon(false);
     }
  }
  for (Player player : getAllPlayers())
  {
     //set win for player with largest result
     resultToTest = player.getResult();
     if (resultToTest == bestResult) {
        player.setWon(true);
        player.setPoints(player.getPoints() + player.getBet());
     }
     else if (resultToTest < bestResult){
        player.setPoints(player.getPoints() - player.getBet()); 
     }
```

Answer (score 0):

It would be better to use indexes:

```
final List<Player> players = getAllPlayers(); // or Player[] or Collection<Player>
int besti = 0;
int bestpts = players.get(0);

for (int i=1; i<players.size(); i++) {
    final int curpts = players.get(i).getResult();
    if (curpts > bestpts) {
        bestpts = curpts;
        besti = i;
    }
}

for (int i=0; i<players.size(); i++)
    players.get(i).setWon(i == besti);
```